# Can sinon fakeserver send xml response?

Tags: javascript, xml, sinon

I want to fake a server where its response is in xml. How can i do that?

```
     server.respondWith(
        "GET",
        "testurl",
        [
          200,
          {
            "Content-Type": "application/xml",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, must-revalidate",
            "Connection": "close"
          },
          <note></note>
        ]
      );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mock a response with `respondWith`, the third argument of the method is an array describing the desired response. The third element of the array, where you have `<note></note>` is the body of the response, so you can just place the XML as a string there.

```
 var xml = getXmlStringSomehow();
 server.respondWith(
    "GET",
    "testurl",
    [
      200,
      {
        "Content-Type": "application/xml",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, must-revalidate",
        "Connection": "close"
      },
      xml
    ]);
```